# Does pact support application/JavaScript content-type?

Tags: spring, testing, integration-testing, microservices, pact

The third party service that my microservice interacts with returns the response with the content-type application/JavaScript;charset=UTF-8. Therefore, pact json has response body as string & matching rules have an empty body.

Using the following pact dependencies:

```
testIntegrationCompile('au.com.dius:pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.12:3.5.11')
   testIntegrationCompile('au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12:3.5.11')
   testIntegrationCompile('au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12:3.5.11')
   testIntegrationCompile('au.com.dius:pact-jvm-consumer-java8_2.12:3.5.11')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no, Pact does not have support for javascript code. It will just treat the body as as String, as you have noticed. You can still do contract tests with string bodies, but they will be very brittle, as one character difference will make the match fail.

Secondly, what behaviour would you expect if there *was* a matcher for javascript?

Thirdly, Pact is not a good tool for testing a third party API. It is specifically written for consumer driven contract testing, not general API mocking. Please read the docs here: https://docs.pact.io/getting-started/what-is-pact-good-for